# Tried to replace bicycle brake housing. Broken cable?

Tags: brakes, cable, rim-brake, brake-levers

I was attempting to replace my stock front v brake to a better aftermarket v brake everything went ok until I tried to test it and the brake cable end, the one that connects to the brake lever, will not stay in place.

[image: brake lever]

As you can see, the cable gets clamped at the brake lever entrance. On my bicycle the clamp or  ferrule will not stay in place. In other words, the cable does not tighten because it will not clamp into the brake lever, it slides.

My question is.. Can this be fixed? Perhaps I can glue it in somehow? Perhaps there is something that gets clamped in a different way?

Apologies for the vague explanation.

Comment: First and foremost, do not put glue anywhere near this mech! It is quite difficult to tell what is wrong from your description, but really, assuming you put the new calliper on properly, you have only two options here - either the cable is too tight or it is too loose. I'd be surprised if the cable has snapped, just because its not something you see often. If you're really struggling, you should take it to your LBS - it is a trivial job to do

Comment: With most brake levers the cable housing is not "clamped" at the lever but is held in place by tension on the cable inside the housing.

Comment: Cross-reference at: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/23501/what-can-i-use-for-a-diy-cable-end/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two types of brake anchor (one is plum-shaped, the other is barrel-shaped or cylindrical). If you have the wrong one at the brake end, it won't fit properly and will slide around.

To solve this, some brake cable vendors sell their cables with both types of end anchors attached. You just use the end that you need and cut off (with a proper brake line cutter, not a pair of pliers) the end you don't need:

[image]

Be sure to put a ferrule on the cut end of the cable because it will unravel. DIY options include shrink wrap, a cork, an electrical crimp connector, tape (not personally recommended), string, wire, hot glue, etc.

Comment: +1 As green tick implies this was the solution!

Comment: Or just let it fray, to match the other cables on the bike.

Comment: I inevitably poke myself underneath the fingernail with the brake cable strands when adjusting my brakes. The only thing worse is banging shins against spiked pedals. So now I ferrule.